# How to authorise action against account that have multiple users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The desired outcome would be that users can create account for company becoming first employee for that company having super-admin role. He then can create other employee accounts that have access to company account.

For that I have two models

1. Team (the company account)
2. User (the employee account)

and there is `one-to-many` relationship between team and user.

I have added global scope to `User` model in order to automatically load associated team so it would be easy to display necessary information in views.

The `User` model is authenticable.

Users can have different permissions. For example only super-admin is allowed to delete other user from team. I am following the Laravel way to authenticate action by using custom requests

```
public function destroy(DeleteTeamUserRequest $request, $id)
{
   $this->users->deleteById($id);
   return redirect()->route('dashboard')->withFlashSuccess('Deleted User');
}

class DeleteTeamUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return $this->user()->isSuperAdmin();
    }
 }
```

This way I can be sure that user without super-admin role wouldnt delete other user. However theoretically super-admin of company 1 is able to to delete user form company 2. Of course he would never have that url in frontend but if he tempers the code he has the permission to delete all users.

I could always check in controller that given user is within the team but thats just wrong.

I made both `Users` and `Teams` authenticable (create another web guard for team), manually log in the team once user logs in (the same on logout) but came upon the same problem - I have to check if user I try to delete is within the same team as user that performs the action.

```
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return $this->user()->isSuperAdmin()
            && $this->team()->has($otherUser); // I dont have other user here
    }
 }
```

The scenario should be quite common but I couldnt find a good explanation on how to properly handle these cases so I would highly appreciate any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the route param in the FormRequest like this:

```
$otherUserId = $this->route('id');
```

You can just fetch the other user and its team and compare that with the team of the authenticated user.

You can also write a little helper/service which can do the same; check if 2 users are part of the same team.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing multi tenancy in your application. Many different users or groups of users having access to the same software but restricted to their data only.
Basically what you want is a `team_id` on the tables that have relationships to the team of a given user.

Typically, a middleware checks that a user belongs to a team and has the task of scoping queries for the duration of the request. For example, the middleware would add a `where` clause to every query made during the request lifecycle of the form `->where('team_id, auth()->user()->team->id)`.

This would prevent users with super admin roles from cross polluting or deleting other team's data because the `where` clause would not allow for it.

There a few really good packages that provide this functionality and then some. My personal favorite is [Landlord](https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/Landlord).